# Error in parameter value on callback function Python + C DLL

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I have a C dll that exports this function:

```
DECLDIR int runTest (char *historyPath, unsigned int candleNumber, void (*testUpdate)(double percentageOfTestCompleted), void (*testFinished)(void), char **error);
```

I'm trying to use the function inside my python script this way:

```
historyFilePath_c = c_char_p(historyFilePath)
candleNumber_c = c_int(1000)
error_c = c_char_p(300);

TEST_UPDATE = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_double))
testUpdate_c = TEST_UPDATE(testUpdate)

TEST_FINISHED = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)
testFinished_c = TEST_FINISHED(testFinished)

astdll.runTest (historyFilePath_c, candleNumber_c, testUpdate_c, testFinished_c, byref(error_c))

def testUpdate(percentageOfTestCompleted):
  print 'Test running ' , percentageOfTestCompleted[0]
  return True

def testFinished():
  print 'Test finished!!'
  return True
```

I'm getting this error (several times because the callback function is running many times. I'll leave just the last error. All of them are the same)

```
Test running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
  File "ast.py", line 67, in testUpdate
    print 'Test running ' , percentageOfTestCompleted[0]
ValueError: NULL pointer access
Test finished!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `testUpdate` callback takes a `double` by value, not a pointer, and both callbacks return `void`, i.e. `None`.

`candleNumber_c` is unnecessary, especially if you declare `argtypes`. The same applies to `historyFilePath_c`. A Python string already contains a pointer to a null-terminated string, which is what the `c_char_p` constructor uses.

Why do you initialize `error_c` to the address 300?

Here's an example that should help:

**tmp.py:**

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL('./tmp.so')

c_test_update_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_double)
c_test_finished_t = CFUNCTYPE(None)

run_test = lib.runTest
run_test.argtypes = [
    c_char_p, c_uint, c_test_update_t, c_test_finished_t, 
    POINTER(c_char_p)]

def test_update(percent_completed):
    print 'percent completed:', percent_completed
test_update_c = c_test_update_t(test_update)

def test_finished():
    print 'test finished'
test_finished_c = c_test_finished_t(test_finished)

error = c_char_p()
result = run_test(
    'path/to/history', 1000, test_update_c, test_finished_c,
    byref(error))

print result
print error.value
```

---

**tmp.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char error_string[] = "error string";

int runTest(
      char *historyPath,
      unsigned int candleNumber,
      void (*testUpdate)(double percentageOfTestCompleted),
      void (*testFinished)(void),
      char **error)
{
    printf("historyPath: %s\n", historyPath);
    printf("candleNumber: %d\n", candleNumber);
    testUpdate(0.0);
    testFinished();
    *error = error_string;
    return 0;
}
```

*(Just a simple test lib, compiled with gcc on Linux)*

---

**Output:**

```
historyPath: path/to/history
candleNumber: 1000
percent completed: 0.0
test finished
0
error string
```